# Get Twitter user count

Tags: php, twitter

I have inherited this bit of (PHP) code in a website which gets the Twitter followers of the account, but it is returning the following in the error log:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://twitter.com/users/show/twitterusername): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r
```

Where 'twitterusername' is my twitter username. If I go to that URL in a browser it does indeed return a page not found. I suspect Twitter has changed something here at some stage (don;t know when) which has caused this to fail and this script needs updating.

Could anyone help me out with what needs changing to return the Twitter count?

Thanks in advance. Code below:

```
$cache = get_transient('twitterfollowerscount' . $username);

if ($cache) {
    $count = get_option('twitterfollowerscount' . $username);
    if($count ==0){
        $url = 'http://twitter.com/users/show/' . urlencode($username);
        $xml=file_get_contents($url);
        if (preg_match('/followers_count>(.*)</',$xml,$match)!=0) {
        $count = $match[1];
        }
        set_transient('twitterfollowerscount' . $username, 'true',  60 * 30);
        update_option('twitterfollowerscount' . $username, $count);
    }
} else {
    $url = 'http://twitter.com/users/show/' . urlencode($username);
    $xml=file_get_contents($url);
    if (preg_match('/followers_count>(.*)</',$xml,$match)!=0) {
    $count = $match[1];
    }
    set_transient('twitterfollowerscount' . $username, 'true',  60 * 30);
    update_option('twitterfollowerscount' . $username, $count);
}
return $count;
}
```

Comment: You should look at the Twitter API and rewrite that PHP code to suit it.

Answer (score 0):

Its much easier to use the Twitter API and use the `followers/list` request to get a list of your follower.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/list

And it much better if Twitter changes something in the URL structure like you have now.